# Is commercial Cactus and Succulent MIx appropriate for Lithops potting in Southern California

Tags: succulents, potting-soil, climate

I live in the city of Riverside California which is in Southern California.  Wikipedia shows the climate to be semi arid bordering on arid (we may have crossed the border).  I just purchased 2 species of unknown Lithops that will live outside in pots. I have read the vendors suggestions and searched the internet for information about the proper soil mix.  A few of the suggestions were for a mix that was just small rough pebbles with little or no organic material.

Is the commercial cactus and succulent mix that I use for my cacti appropriate for Lithops (and 'split rock') or do I need to add inorganic material and if so, what?

Answer (score 2):

We are growing Lithops inside in what appears to be 100% grit  (finely crushed sharp stone).  Grit is sometimes sold in feed stores for chickens.  I read a few articles and the suggestions for planting ranged from 100% inorganics  (perlite, sand) to an ordinary potting soil mix.

I suggest that soil mix is not as important as the water it will receive. As long as

- the mixture is free draining
- temperatures do not go below zero degrees Celsius
- there is no water in summer and winter as the growing seasons are spring and fall

If you are planting outside the local soil is always preferable so as long as the inorganic matter is high and the drainage is good you should be fine.  Plant so that when it does rain the area drains quickly.
[This article](https://www.mediterraneangardensociety.org/100-lithops.html) was helpful.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot to add that I will grow them in pots! No way they will grow in the soil here.  I take it that I should move then into cover when rain is expected, our rain, what little we get, is mostly in the winter ...